# How to Create a Key - Value object from a list of objets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am fairly new to react and have a query regarding how to create a key-value pair object in react using data returned to an axios get call to a webservice. Save the object in the state and later on read the values based on the keys.

```
axios.get('/api/locations/')
    .then(r => r.data )
    .then(types => this.setState({types}))
```

I am getting a `List<LocationType>` back from the backend and `LocationType` object has two property :

```
String locationId
String locationName
```

Now I want to create a hashmap using the types object as below:

```
{ "1": "London", "2": "Berlin"...... etc}
```

I am trying to do something like this but not really sure how i can assign the key value to a object

```
axios.get('/api/locations/types')
    .then(r => r.data )
    .then(types => this.setState({types}))
    .then(types => {
        this.state.types.map((type => {
            //create a map object and here but how?
        }))
    })
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what is 1, 2, ... just the number or any specific keys?

Comment: @MayankShukla is an object with keys 1, 2, 3, and following numbers. That is what I think it is

Comment: how about returning an array like this `["London", "Berlin", .... etc]`

Comment: A key/value object with numeric keys is not that useful.  An array is much more useful.

Comment: @James what if we need to access the data frequently then map would be helpful because of constant time lookup, but array will take time to iterate (not that significant but can be avoided by map).

Comment: @MayankShukla If you know the index of the array element (which, if you know the "key" of the object you effectively do) - there is no lookup time difference between myArray[0] and myObject["0"]

Comment: @James you are right, yea i missed that part thanks :)

Comment: @MayankShukla yes they are the Ids for the location (i.e. location.id)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reduce`

```
this.setState(() => {
  return {
    types: types.reduce((map, type) => {
     map[type. locationId] = type.locationName;
     return map;
   }, {})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a map of `localionNames`, run a loop on data and prepare an object first. Also instead of doing `setState` twice, you can do in one call.

Write it like this:

```
axios.get('/api/locations/types')
  .then(r => r.data)
  .then(types => {

    // map object
    let mapObj = {};

    // run a loop on types and create the map
    types.forEach((type, i) => {
      mapObj[type.locationId] = type.locationName;
    })

    // update all the values in single setState
    this.seState({ types, typesMap: mapObj })
  })
```